# How to convert .xlsx (excelsheet) into .resx file(Resource file)?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, resx

I am dealing with a global application. We have 5 to 6 language translation available and that many resource files created. I want some hack or technique to convert excel file into the resource file.

We manually added translation using copy+paste but it is not a feasible solution

```
<pre>
English     Spanish         German          Czech
Add Color   Añadir Color    Neue Farbe      Nová barva
Add Defect  Añadir Defecto  Neuer Defekt    Nová chyba
</pre>
```

There are more than ***200 words(200*6 language= 1200 Copy+paste)***
Is there any way to convert excel to resx file?

Comment: An easy way is to create a script. I don't see another easy solution.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can read or write to Resource file using below code:

```
using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                    + @"Properties\Resources.resx"))
                {
                    Entries = reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList();
                    var existingResource = Entries.Where(r => r.Key.ToString().ToLower()
                    == Key.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (existingResource.Key == null && existingResource.Value == null)
                    {
                        Entries.Add(new DictionaryEntry() { Key = Key, Value = Value });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var modifiedResx = new DictionaryEntry()
                        { Key = existingResource.Key, Value = Value };
                        Entries.Remove(existingResource);
                        Entries.Add(modifiedResx);
                    }
                }
                using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                    + @"Properties\Resources.resx"))
                {
                    Entries.ForEach(r =>
                    {
                        writer.AddResource(r.Key.ToString(), r.Value.ToString());
                    });
                    writer.Generate();
                }
```

Read your excel into a list, loop through and use the above code to read/write to it. Hope this might help you

Comment: Hey, I have a doubt.... From where the "Entries" came from?
This what I passed---
List<DictionaryEntry> Entries = "C:/Users/1dehades/Desktop/ScrapApp.xlsx";
 (I want to pass the .xlsx file name and convert it to .resx).

Comment: Entiries are of type List<DictionaryEntry>. First you need to read your Excel file into a list. You can either use normal excel driver to read or use ExcelDataReader nuget package so that you can read the file. Once you read it you can loop through and use the above code to write it to Resource file.